# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in .asp.net mvc when adding data to a view modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

am tring to add data to a view model, so my view can display those data but am having this issue

```
 using (var db = new Models.PVDB01Entities())
                {
                    var eventName = (from p in db.EventDetails where p.EventID == id select new { p.Title }).SingleOrDefault();
                    ViewBag.EventName = eventName;
                    var q = db.Events.Find(id);
                    Event evt = new Event();
                    if (q != null) {
                        //  evt.eventDetail.Title = q.EventDetail.Title;
                        evt.eventDetail.Title = "sksk";
                        evt.eventDetail.Cateogory = q.EventDetail.Category;
                        evt.eventDetail.Description = q.EventDetail.Description;
                        evt.eventDetail.Start = q.EventDetail.StartDate;
                        evt.eventDetail.Stop = Convert.ToDateTime(q.EventDetail.EndDate);

                        evt.eventLocation.City = q.EventLocation.City;
                        evt.eventLocation.Country = q.EventLocation.Country;
                        evt.eventLocation.State = q.EventLocation.State;
                        evt.eventLocation.VenueAddress = q.EventLocation.VenueAddress;
                        evt.eventLocation.VenueName = q.EventLocation.VenueName;
                        return View(evt);
                    }
```

when i run this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this is the view model i want to set
i have an eventDetails class , eventLocation Class, and event class,
the event class combines eventDetails and eventLocation, the reason for that is because i have a view that makes use of those two class.

```
public class EventDetails
    {
        public string eventID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Package { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Title for address")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Give a short description of the event ")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select a category")]
        public string Cateogory { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date and Time event will Start")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Choose when the event will start")]
        public DateTime Start { get; set; } 

        [Display(Name ="Date and Time event will Stop")]
        public DateTime Stop { get; set; }
    }
    public class EventLoction
    {
        public string eventID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide the venue name")]
        [Display(Name ="Name of venue")]
        public string VenueName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Address of venue")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Provide the venue address")]
        public string VenueAddress { get; set; }

    }
    public class Event
    {
        public EventDetails eventDetail {get; set;}
        public EventLoction eventLocation { get; set; } 
    }
```

The Error Starts at this line

```
 evt.eventDetail.Title = "sksk";
```

this is the stack trace

```
Stack trace ` [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Pluravent1._1._0.Controllers.EventController.Edit(String id) in E:\ProJects\Pluravent1.1.0\Pluravent1.1.0\Controllers\EventController.cs:129
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9765121
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155 `
```

Comment: From which line you are getting the error? Can you post your runtime stack? It has the problem indicated there in...

Comment: the error is at line 129, 
`Line 127:                    if (q != null) {
Line 128:                        //  evt.eventDetail.Title = q.EventDetail.Title;
Line 129:                        evt.eventDetail.Title = "sksk";
Line 130:                        evt.eventDetail.Cateogory = q.EventDetail.Category;
Line 131:                        evt.eventDetail.Description = q.EventDetail.Description; `

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i don't see a EndDate property for EventDetail class

```
evt.eventDetail.Stop = Convert.ToDateTime(q.EventDetail.EndDate);
```